# UITableview Inside Another UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4.1, uitableviewautomaticdimension

How to handle table view inside another table view with height  as UITableViewautomaticdimension ?
The content inside the inner tableview is dyanamic

Comment: you can create separate classes by defining protocols for both tableview's delegate and dataSource. In this manner, you will easily understand and will stay away from complexity.

Comment: If you must use nested tableviews (and you might want to re-think that approach) You will need to compute a reasonable value for the desired height for the inner tableview based on the number of rows in it and then set a height constraint on the inner tableview

Comment: Why put a table inside each row? Just use one table. Use different sections.

Answer (score 1):

Please use `different section` instead of `nested tableView`.It may helps to you.Thank you